# Subversion commit fails on cygwin (FSFS backend only)

Tags: svn, cygwin, fsfs

I'm trying to create a Subversion repository on Cygwin, but I'm unable to add any content.  When I try to commit, I get the error "svn: E160004: Invalid changes line in rev-file".  Here's my workflow:

1. Create a new repository

   `svnadmin create ~/repo`
2. Check out repository to working directory

   `mkdir ~/working`
   `svn co file:///home/username/repo ~/working`
3. Add content to repository

   `mkdir -p ~/working/myproject/trunk`
   `cd ~/working`
   `echo "Blah" > myproject/trunk/file.txt`
   `svn add myproject`
   `svn commit -m "Commit message"`

The last step fails with the following message:

```
Adding         myproject
Adding         myproject/trunk
Adding         myproject/trunk/file.txt
Transmitting file data .svn: E160004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160004: Invalid changes line in rev-file
```

I also tried a different workflow.  I tried creating the working directory, adding content, then using `svn import` to add the content to the repository.  But I get the same result.

The strange part is that if I create the repository using the BDB backend instead of FSFS, it works fine.  I can add content without problems.  I tried adding content to a BDB-backed repository, creating an FSFS-backed repository, and copying the data using svnadmin dump/load, but I get the same error when I try to add content to the FSFS-backed repository.  I'd prefer to use FSFS if possible for interoperability purposes and ease of backup/restore.

I thought maybe the commit hooks were the problem.  When I created the repository, I saw that all of the sample hooks were executable.  I used `chmod a-x` to make the sample hooks non-executable, but that didn't fix the error.  I'm not using any commit hooks.

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.  I'm using the 32-bit installation of Cygwin.  I just updated Cygwin yesterday and installed Subversion, so the software is at the newest version.

Comment: Why aren't you using the native Windows binaries for Subversion?

Comment: I already had cygwin installed, and I prefer a command-line environment.  I have TortoiseSVN installed, but its command-line tools don't understand cygwin-style paths, so I would rather stick with cygwin if possible.

Comment: Why are you trying to use cygwin style paths with native Win32 binaries? Subversion runs perfectly well as a native Win32 app, both client and server.